# diposit.js wont do what it should

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, discord.js

with my bot I have withdraw and deposit setup but I have a slight bug or issue may have coded it slightly wrong but when I try to -deposit 100 or any number it says deposit must be a hole number.

```
const profileModel = require("../models/profileSchema");
module.exports = {
  name: "deposit",
  aliases: ["dep"],
  permissions: [],
  description: "Deposit gold into your bank!",
  async execute(message, args, cmd, client, discord, profileData) {
    const amount = args[0];
    if (amount % 1 != 0 || amount <= 0) return message.channel.send("Deposit amount must be a whole number");
    try {
      if (amount > profileData.gold) return message.channel.send(`You don't have that amount of gold to deposit`);
      await profileModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
          userID: message.author.id,
        },
        {
          $inc: {
            gold: -amount,
            bank: amount,
          },
        }
      );

      return message.channel.send(`You deposited ${amount} of gold into your bank`);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  },
};
```

both withdraw and deposit are setup the same just changes in the amount bit instead of - its +

Comment: Log `amount` and make sure it's what you're expecting it to be. Either `amount % 1 != 0 ` or `amount <= 0` is returning true

Comment: It seems `args[0]` is a falsy value. As Elitezen mentioned, try to log it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a nicer way to do a `withdraw` and `deposit` command, and I don't know why you need to get a whole number to make it that way. I modified your code to something easier and cleaner.

```
const amount = parseFloat(args[0]); // Your current code: const amount = args[0];
//if (amount % 1 != 0 || amount <= 0) return message.channel.send("Deposit amount must be a whole number");
try {
    // > = Greater than and < = Less than.
    if (amount > profileData.gold) return message.channel.send(`You don't have that amount of gold to deposit`);
    // await profileModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    //     {
    //     userID: message.author.id,
    //     },
    //     {
    //     $inc: {
    //         gold: -amount,
    //         bank: amount,
    //     },
    //     }
    // );
    await profileModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
            userID: message.author.id,
        },
        { $inc: { gold: amount } },
        async (err, data) => {
            if (data) {
                //No data returns a message
            } else {
                (data.bank += amount), (data.gold -= amount);

                return message.channel.send(`You deposited ${amount} of gold into your bank`);
            }
        }
    );
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

`parseFloat()`

```
1e0 = 1
1e1 = 10
1e2 = 100
1e3 = 1,000
1e4 = 10,000

and so on
```